# i want to get position in a list data how to get the position of click of button in android

Tags: android

how to get the position from list on click of data.
i want access button in android.on the click of button of the adapter class it should give the position.

```
holder.beginDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: position in this method passed as argument is the position of button

Comment: On button click how would adapter understand what listview item's position you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the position as the tag

```
holder.beginDate.setTag(position); // set every time getting the View
```

and retrieve it using

```
// put this code where creating a new instance of holder
holder.beginDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        int pos = (Integer) view.getTag();
        // do anything using the position
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After initialization of your button in getView() method write:

```
holder.beginDate.setTag(position);
```

and in your onClick() use:

```
holder.beginDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        int position=Integer.parseInt(((Button)v).getTag().toString());

    }
});
```